# Enable TV out function of VGA port

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga, tv

I have PAL TV. i want to connect it to my computer (with intel HD graphics). On the internet I found this:
[VGA to RCA converter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/15Pin-Male-VGA-To-4Pin-Female-S-Video-S-Video-RCA-TV-PC-Cable-Adapter-Converter-/140722246469?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item20c3b31345) But it has a note that my computer's graphic card must have VGA tv out capability!

what does it mean ! I can see a custom resolution setting in my graphic card control panel but the Tv / monitor settings panel says monitor tv settings are not supported!

Is it locked by manufacturer driver? if so can I use it with original drivers from intel?

Comment: I think VGA tv out simply means you've got a VGA out connector and can set your graphics card to a TV-compatible resolution (625 vertical lines for PAL). Note the converter you're looking at has an [S-Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-video) connector on the TV side -- so make sure your TV has that sort of input port. Also note there are 4- and 7-pin versions of S-Video connectors. The article also says in that in EU countries "S-Video is less common because of the dominance of [SCART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART), which allows RGB quality and is usually fitted to every TV."